# How Do I Send Data From PC To Phone c#

Tags: c#, android, ios

So recently I had the idea that I could build an app that would remotely monitor a computers performance such as : CPU & GPU Usage , CPU & GPU Temperature and RAM Usage.

This app would allow people to check there pc's performance if it was left on rendering while they where out or, if they where playing a game and didn't like the idea of having the data in the corner like MSI afterburner does.

I have built a simple Windows Form App using C# which pulls the data every second form the performance monitor and displays it in the form. Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace cpu_monitor
{
    public partial class Monitor : Form
    {

        PerformanceCounter perfCPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information","% Processor Time", "_Total");
        PerformanceCounter perfMEMCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
        PerformanceCounter perfSYSTEMCounter = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");

        public Monitor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Monitor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CPU_label.Text = "CPU: " + " " + (int)perfCPUCounter.NextValue() + " " + "%" ;
            MEMORY_label.Text = "Available Memory: " + " " + (int)perfMEMCounter.NextValue() + " " + "MB";
            SYSTEM_label.Text = "System up time: " + " " + (int)perfSYSTEMCounter.NextValue()/60/60 + " " +"Hours";

        }
    }
}
```

My only problem now is how do i go about sending this data to a receiving app on platforms such as ios or android.

My main question is the logistics of it. Would i have to send the data to a server and then pull it from the server using the app or could i do it using a website.
Or does anyone have any other ideas.
I am using c# for the pc program and i dont know about the app .
Any help would be gratefully needed.
Thanks, richard.

Comment: i didnt know what language to use

Comment: Unfortunately this is a very broad question. There are so many ways to communicate between devices depending on if it needs to work in the same network or also outside, among other things. I don’t think this is a good fit at SO due to this.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you created desktop application that suppose to be on desktop

what you need to do is **server** that will have API for sending information to it and reciving information from it

on your pc you can make windows service that will be sending to the web server information after x sec for updating the cpu/mem data and at your mobile you need to create application that will using the same API client for getting the last information about your performans.

that is not something i can write here but you get the idea.

**best advice for making the applications:**

- server side: NodeJS
- moblie application (Android/IOS): react native
- client side
  (windows): windows service

for hosting the server API you can use https://www.heroku.com/

for makeing react application use : https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app , tool which lets you build Android and iOS app on your windows/linux machine without having to install Xcode or Android Studio, using the Expo SDK and app.

firebase could also be usefull.

Good luck

Comment: +1 so can i use the desktop app that i have built then send the data from that to a server and then request it back from the server on the application for mobile.

Comment: yes you can add web service reference to your winform application.

Comment: the problem with this idea is that you need to keep the application alive when windows service will always run at backround

Comment: good luck, it's lot of work but if you will do it by steps it's easy and fun

Comment: yeah just a question . for the server, do i need to own a server/host my own or do i have to rent one

Comment: for server you can make it on your pc but for that you need to keep your pc always on and get a static ip from your internet provider but i recomend for  hosting use heroku  www.heroku.com